# Considerable delays between calling URLLoader, and seeing bytes on the wire

Tags: actionscript-3, urlloader

**Context**: An AS3 application using a [BOSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH) solution to asynchronously send and receive messages from a server.

I am endeavouring to find the source of a delay between calls to URLLoader.load(), and observing the HTTP request on the wire with Wireshark. The delay is unpredictable and can be 30s or more. A reliable reproduction has not been possible.

I have been able to eliminate:

1. **Network congestion**: there is no TCP retransmission, no part of the journey to the server crosses a network that is the Internet or otherwise likely to suffer congestion.
2. **Exceeding the HTTP transaction limit**. At most there are two concurrent HTTP transactions.

Has anyone any wisdom they can share share?

Comment: By _observing bytes_ are you referring to receiving a response or before the request is sent?

Comment: Thanks Jason, some clarification made to the body of the question. Wireshark is used to observe a delay in the **request** being visible on the network